# Find basis $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that the transformation matrix L has a specific shape

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank, change-of-basis

So I'm currently studying for an exam of linear algebra and there is this exercise that I cannot seem to find even how to start with. The question is the following:

"Let $L: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ be a linear map with a matrix:

A = $ \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 \\
4 & 6 \\
6 & 9 
\end{bmatrix}  $

This matrix is defined with respects to the standard basis for both $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ (so $A = L^{\mathbb{R}^3}_{\mathbb{R}^2}$). Find a basis $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\beta$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $L^{\mathbb{R}^3}_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ is a matrix with the specific shape:

$ \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{I}_r & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}  $

(Here $r$ is the rank of the matrix)"

How should I solve this problem? I'm literally stuck since I don't even know how I would start.

Comment: what is $\mathbb{I}_r$?

Comment: It is the identity matrix with $r$ rows and $r$ columns